# no muestra la información al cargar un archivo - react native

Tags: react-native

buen día, tengo un boton que me carga un archivo desde el celular y funciona pero necesito mostrar la información del archivo que seleccione como es el nombre, tamaño etc y `console.log('res : ' + JSON.stringify(res));` me muestra la información pero no he podido hacer que me muestre la información en la vista del dispositivo  me aparece undefined no me muestra la información.

```js
import DocumentPicker from 'react-native-document-picker';

const App = () => {
  const [singleFile, setSingleFile] = useState('');
  
  const selectOneFile = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await DocumentPicker.pick({
        type: [DocumentPicker.types.allFiles],
      });
      console.log('res : ' + JSON.stringify(res));
      console.log('URI : ' + res.uri);
      console.log('Type : ' + res.type);
      console.log('File Name : ' + res.name);
      console.log('File Size : ' + res.size);
      setSingleFile(res);
    } catch (err) {
      if (DocumentPicker.isCancel(err)) {
        alert('Canceled from single doc picker');
      } else {
        alert('Unknown Error: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        throw err;
      }
    }
  };
  
  return (
  <TouchableOpacity
          activeOpacity={0.5}
          style={styles.buttonStyle}
          onPress={selectOneFile}>
          <Text style={{marginRight: 10, fontSize: 19}}>
            Click here to pick one file
          </Text>
          <Image
            source={{
              uri: 'https://img.icons8.com/offices/40/000000/attach.png',
            }}
            style={styles.imageIconStyle}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
          File Name: {singleFile.name ? singleFile.name : ''}
          {'\n'}
          Type: {singleFile.type ? singleFile.type : ''}
          {'\n'}
          File Size: {singleFile.size ? singleFile.size : ''}
          {'\n'}
          URI: {singleFile.uri ? singleFile.uri : ''}
          {'\n'}
        </Text>
  
  )
```

consola
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que el resultado te lo está mandando en un Array, puedes ver los [] antes de las {} en tu código.

Colocar res dentro de corchetes podría hacerlo más fácil y legible.
Así desestructuras el Array y te quedas con sus valores en res.
Ejemplo.

```
  const selectOneFile = async () => {
    try {
      /**
      * Coloca res dentro de llaves para desestructurar 
      * const [res] = await...
      * Y no const res = await. También puedes colocar res[0] en cada 
      * llamada pero sería menos practico.
      */
      const [res] = await DocumentPicker.pick({
        type: [DocumentPicker.types.allFiles],
      });
      console.log('res : ' + JSON.stringify(res));
      console.log('URI : ' + res.uri);
      console.log('Type : ' + res.type);
      console.log('File Name : ' + res.name);
      console.log('File Size : ' + res.size);
      setSingleFile(res);
    } catch (err) {
      if (DocumentPicker.isCancel(err)) {
        alert('Canceled from single doc picker');
      } else {
        alert('Unknown Error: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        throw err;
      }
    }
  };
```